# Can anyone help me with this calculus variational problem?

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I'm having some problem finding the optimal trajectory $y^*(t)$:

$$V(y)=\int_{0}^{3}(y'+40t^3y)dt$$ with $y(0)=2$ and $y(3)=y_3$, with $y_3$ varying.

Basically, when I apply the Euler-Lagrange equation, the result is: $$F_{y}-\frac{dF_{y'}}{dt}=40t^3-0=0$$

Which doesn't make sense to me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Perhaps there is no optimal trajectory. You can integrate the $y'$ piece to get $\int_0^3 y'(t) dt = y(3) - y(0) = 1.$ What's left can be made as small as you want.

Comment: Sorry Trevor, I edit the question, actually my $y(3)$ can vary.

Comment: The functional (v3) is still unbounded.